# How to get this resque job to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

I want to have a Resque worker get sentiment via the Viralheat API for tags for a brand instance
(belongs to User) in the background, and then save the mood parameter of that response to a Tag.

**Update**:

I've revised the code and now the worker fails because it says undefined method `score` for nil:NilClass. That's happening because `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging.find_by_tag_id(tag.id).score.create` has no tag.id to check against, also I don't think .create is valid Ruby.

Viralheat API response (JSON) format:

```
{"prob":0.537702567133646,"mood":"positive","text":"hello, goodbye"}
```

**Controller**:

```
def update
  @brand = Brand.find(params[:id])
  current_user.tag(@brand, :with => params[:brand][:tag_list], :on => :tags)
  if @brand.update_attributes(params[:brand])
    redirect_to :root, :notice => "Brand tagged."
  else
    render :action => 'edit'
  end
  Resque.enqueue(SentimentJob, @brand.tags)
end
```

**sentiment_job.rb Worker**:

```
require 'resque-retry'

class SentimentJob
  @queue = :sentiment_pull

  def self.perform(tags)

    tags.each do |tag|
    url = "http://www.viralheat.com/api/sentiment/review.json"
    @sentiment_response = url.to_uri.get(
        :api_key => 'MY KEY',
        :text => tag.name.to_s ).deserialize          

    #If I comment out the 3 lines below, the worker runs and I get 3 successful callbacks but can't save them.

    @sentiment_value = @sentiment_response[:mood]
    @sentiment_store = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging.find_by_tag_id(tag.id).score.create(@sentiment_value)
    @sentiment_store.save
    end
  end
end
```

**Tagggings table**:

```
create_table "taggings", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer "tag_id"
  t.integer "taggable_id"
  t.string "taggable_type"
  t.integer "tagger_id"
  t.string "tagger_type"
  t.string "context"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.string "Sentiment"
end
```

Comment: Hi, first off, can you please share the complete error with stack trace for the same ? Secondly, taggable does not have any 'score', can  you also indicate what you intend to do with 'score' ?

Comment: This is very simple. All i need to know to give you working code is the following. 1 - what is "score", 2 - In a plain english just tell me what you want the job to do.

Comment: score is just the value of the sentiment response. I want the job to send each tag to Viralheat, get a sentiment value e.g positive, and save it with the tag in the tagging table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your argument list: `def self.perform(tag.id, user_id)` should be `def self.perform(tag_id, user_id)` (note the underscore).

#### Update

You shouldn't be using instance variables in a Resque Job. You are actually trying to use `@brand` before you declare it.

You are trying to get information from `params`. There is no request, and thus no `params`. You probably want to swap out that find argument with the `tag_id` argument.

The order you are queueing arguments is getting flipped. Your `enqueue` call is specifying the `user_id` before the `tag_id`. The job is expecting the `tag_id` before the `user_id`.

And since you updated your question, you have switched the `tag_id` argument into `tags_id`. I don't know if you realize this, but calling `brand.tags.id` will probably return just a single id (I'm not too familiar with `acts_as_taggable`).

Comment: Changed that but still getting exception in the controller for undefined method tag which is weird because `Brand.first.tags.first.id` returns an id.

Comment: Hey Corey. I accepted prematurely thinking I'd understood your update but it didn't work so I've updated my question.

Comment: As noted via email, you need to manually serialize `@brand.tags` into either ids or strings and then load the actual ActsAsTaggable objects in your job.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - Fix your controller so it's only running the job on success.

```
def update
  @brand = Brand.find(params[:id])
  current_user.tag(@brand, :with => params[:brand][:tag_list], :on => :tags)
  if @brand.update_attributes(params[:brand])
    redirect_to :root, :notice => "Brand tagged."
    #update was successful, create the job
    Resque.enqueue(SentimentJob, @brand.tags)
  else
    render :action => 'edit'
  end
end
```

Step 2 - Fix your table columns, you can't use the Camel Case naming with PG on heroku, saw in an earlier post you were on heroku, this will give you issue.

so run `rails g migration FixColumnName`

go into your db/migrate folder and find the migration

paste this into it

```
class FixColumnName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    rename_column :taggings, :Sentiment, :sentiment
  end

  def self.down
    # rename back if you need or do something else or do nothing
  end
end
```

run `rake db:migrate`

Step 3 - Fix your worker so that it does what you want it to do.

Please note - I have completely ignored your "score" method as there is no mention of it in your code, and you don't say anywhere in your question what it is used for or what it should be doing.

```
require 'resque-retry'

class SentimentJob
  @queue = :sentiment_pull

  def self.perform(tags)

    tags.each do |tag|
    url = "http://www.viralheat.com/api/sentiment/review.json"
    @sentiment_response = url.to_uri.get(
        :api_key => 'MY KEY',
        :text => tag.name.to_s ).deserialize          


    #find the tag
    @tag = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging.find_by_tag_id(tag.id)

    #set the tags value for the field sentiment to @sentiment_response[:mood]
    @tag.sentiment = @sentiment_response[:mood]

    #save the tag
    @tag.save

    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Followed that exactly and get this error on Resque https://gist.github.com/1248583

Comment: Problem is that Resque.enqueue(SentimentJob, @brand.tags) in console returns [] but @brand.tags returns 2 tag objects. That's why there's the whiny nil. Not understanding it, why wouldn't it pass through the tags?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand.  The gist was deleted.